# Can the full site button on chat have a confirmation?

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

The current full site button in chat is under the menu, right above the "My Rooms" button. On smaller phones, it is easy to misclick and hit this button.

I (and I believe most mobile chat users) use "My rooms" heavily since I can keep track of many chat rooms with one mobile tab. So I end up opening the full site by accident a lot.

The issue is, getting back from the full site is hard. Usually the full site takes some time to load, and once loaded the "mobile" button sometimes overflows the screen and can't be clicked.

Could the "full site" button on mobile chat have a confirmation dialog?

Comment: Or be moved to a more convenient place...